# Execute Airflow DAG remotely

Tags: airflow

Is it possible to execute an airflow DAG remotely via command line?

I know there is an airflow command line tool but it seems to allow executing from the server's terminal rather than from any external client.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can think of two options here

1. **Experimental Rest API** (preferable): use good-old *`GET` / `POST` requests* to trigger / cancel `DAGRun`s
2. **Airflow CLI**: SSH into the machine running Airflow and trigger the DAG via [command-line](https://airflow.apache.org/cli.html#run)